# Should I use an sd card as a paging file and readyboost with vista on latitude e6400 with 2gb ram?

Tags: windows-vista, memory, sd-card, dell-latitude

Thanks in advance for your time folks.

I bought an older friend of mine a cheap laptop after his died as a bit of charity to a poor friend. He's a giant media fiend movies and music. So I thought I would be able to throw in the 4 gb of ddr3 ram that I had sitting around into this dell latitude e6400, should have asked a different salesman at the Box Shop. So here I have this 32 bit vista system with 2gb ram, a tiny 80gb hd and a Centrino 2.83Ghz cpu. I want to make this system as nice as possible as well as LOCK IT DOWN. He tends to get into trouble and then I have to come over because his computer is "broken" SIGH

I thought I would take a $12 8gb sd card and dedicate 4gb to Readyboost and 4 to paging file to boost performance. Is this the right formula or am I way off? Second what is the best way for me to lock it down so he can't load garbage onto the computer while allowing him to gobble up music and movies?

The man is disabled and his brother cares for him because he doesn't have executive mental functioning like normal folks do, so I need to lock down his ability to use credit cards and such on the computer too or he'll spend his rent money on movies and music. I've solved that by installing Trendmicros Titanium and used the idtheft feature to make it password locked for a fragment of his cc and personal info. Anything you folks could do to give me a walk through of dummy-proofing a system would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unlike SSD, normal flash memory cards aren't designed to balance write operations so that its lifetime will be somewhat short if you use that for page files. And its performance might not be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The [performance of SD cards](http://www.overclock.net/t/1132730/how-would-a-class-10-sd-card-compare-to-a-hdd-or-ssd) is very slow, so you will probably be better off locating the paging file on the hard drive.  They are totally different to SSD cards which are lightning fast - if you can get one of those, then yes, its a good idea to put swap on it.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably see if uncle wally house o' bargains n big 'uns has ssd. Also, still need tips on dummy-proofing his box.